# Getting the last message sent to a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to Kafka and working on a prototype to connect a proprietary streaming service into Kafka.

I'm looking to get the key of the last message sent on a topic as our in-house stream consumer needs to logon with the ID of the last message it received when connecting.

Is it possible, using either the KafkaProducer or a KafkaConsumer to do this?

I've attempted to do the following using a Consumer, but when also running the console consumer I see messages replayed.

```
    // Poll so we know we're connected
    consumer.poll(100);
    // Get the assigned partitions
    Set<TopicPartition> assignedPartitions = consumer.assignment();
    // Seek to the end of those partitions
    consumer.seekToEnd(assignedPartitions);

    for(TopicPartition partition : assignedPartitions) {
        final long offset = consumer.committed(partition).offset();
        // Seek to the previous message
        consumer.seek(partition,offset - 1);
    }

    // Now get the last message
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
        lastKey = record.key();
    }
    consumer.close();
```

Is this expected behaviour or am I on the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on line `final long offset = consumer.committed(partition).offset()`, as [link api](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) refers `committed` method is to get `the last committed offset` for the given partition, i.e: the last offset your consumer tell kafka server that it had already read.
So, definitely you will got `messages replayed`, because you always read from specific offset.
As I think I only have to remove the first for block.

Comment: Of course, i should have checked Consumer.position instead

Comment: @ryanpudd, I am trying to achieve the same thing in a spark program but not able to. Can you please provide a link to your full code? Thanks

Comment: If I've already consumed the last message in a topic partition, won't `seekToEnd()` set the pointer past that last message? How do I re-consume the latest message which I've already consumed?

Answer (score -3):

Check the record count and get the last message:

```
    // Poll so we know we're connected
    consumer.poll(100);
    // Get the assigned partitions
    Set<TopicPartition> assignedPartitions = consumer.assignment();
    // Seek to the end of those partitions
    consumer.seekToEnd(assignedPartitions);

    for (TopicPartition partition : assignedPartitions) {
        final long offset = consumer.committed(partition).offset();
        // Seek to the previous message
        consumer.seek(partition, offset - 1);
    }

    // Now get the last message
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    int size = records.count();
    int index = 0;
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
        index = index + 1;
        if (index == size) {
            String value = record.value();
            System.out.println("Last Message = " + value);
        }
    }
    consumer.close();
```

Comment: getting nullPointerException at


final long offset = kafkaConsumer.committed(partition).offset();

Comment: This works fine most of the time. However, in exactly-once semantics; it will not work.