# How to make restart-able producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Latest version of kafka support exactly-once-semantics (EoS). To support this notion, extra details are added to each message. This means that at your consumer; if you print offsets of messages they won't be necessarily sequential. This makes harder to poll a topic to read the last committed message.

In my case, consumer printed something like this

```
Offset-0 0
Offset-2 1
Offset-4 2
```

Problem: In order to write restart-able proudcer; I poll the topic and read the content of last message. In this case; last message would be offset#5 which is not a valid consumer record. Hence, I see errors in my code.

I can use the solution provided at : [Getting the last message sent to a kafka topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164878/getting-the-last-message-sent-to-a-kafka-topic). The only problem is that instead of using consumer.seek(partition, last_offset=1); I would use consumer.seek(partition, last_offset-2). This can immediately resolve my issue, but it's not an ideal solution.

**What would be the most reliable and best solution to get last committed message for a consumer written in Java?** OR

**Is it possible to use [local state-store](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#id3) for a partition?** OR

**What is the most recommended way to store last message to withstand producer-failure?** OR

**Are kafka connectors restartable? Is there any specific API that I can use to make producers restartable?**

FYI- I am not looking for quick fix

Comment: As per my knowledge, one can use kafka's local data store with streaming API. Is it possible to use something like that for Producer ?

Comment: @matthias j sax

Answer (score 0):

In my case, multiple producers push data to one big topic. Therefore, reading entire topic would be nightmare.

<strike>The solution that I found is to **maintain another topic** i.e. "P1_Track" where producer can store metadata. Within a **transaction** a producer will send data to one big topic and P1_Track.</strike>

When I restart a producer, it will read P1_Track and figure out where to start from.

Thinking about storing last committed message in a database and using it when producer process restarts.