# Reading last Kafka partition's record that's transactionally written

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to read the last record of a topic's partition. The topic's producer is writing transactionally. The consumer is set up with `isolation.level=read_committed`. I manage the offsets manually. Here's my consumer code:

```java
// Fetch the end offset of a partition
Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(Collections.singleton(topicPartition));
Long endOffset = endOffsets.get(topicPartition);

// Try to read the last record
if (endOffset > 0) {
    consumer.seek(topicPartition, Math.max(0, endOffset - 5));
    List records = consumer.poll(10 * 1000).records(topicPartition);

    if (records.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("How can this be?");
    } else {
        // Return the last record
        return records.get(records.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

So to read the last record I ask for the end offset, then seek to `endOffset - 5` (because of Kafka skipping offsets in exactly-once mode, like I've seen in this question: [Kafka Streams does not increment offset by 1 when producing to topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636524/kafka-streams-does-not-increment-offset-by-1-when-producing-to-topic)), and start polling.

It's been working well before, but now I've got an exception telling me zero records are polled. What can be a reason for that? I can't reproduce it and I think I'm lost.

Comment: Are you sure there is a message in the topic?

Comment: Tens of thousands of them.

Comment: Did you change `endOffset - 5` to any greater number?