# How to reduce disk space occupied by a partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, broker

In my specific use-case, we are going to ingest 1000GB of data everyday. If I compress the files locally then it comes about 100GB.

I wrote a sample application to stream 100MB file (which converts to 10MB after compression). Single producer, single topic with single partition.

I have use transactions and enabled compression (gzip). I ran command to find out the total size of the partition and it came about 85MB. As Kafka, might be adding some data; in order to guarantee exactly-once semantics. I create huge batch of messages and commit them in transactions. Each message is compressed.

I also looked at what Kafka has stored internally:

- 0000.index
- 0000.log  (this consumed the most amount of disk-space)
- 0000.timeindex
- 0000.snapshot
- leader-epoch-checkpoint

I have 2 questions:

1. Why Kafka topic uses so much disk space even after compression?
2. What can I do to reduce the disk space of my partition? FYI, log compaction will not be effective in my case, as every message is going to have a unique key.

Comment: Maybe you could try the new ZStandard compression

Comment: As per, https://nehanarkhede.com/2013/03/28/compression-in-kafka-gzip-or-snappy/  gzip does take more time to compress files but it compresses them significantly.

Comment: ZStandard (zstd) is not GZip https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-110%3A+Add+Codec+for+ZStandard+Compression

Comment: Well I mean to say that gzip is the best in terms of compression.

Comment: Maybe used to be. I updated my comment with a reference

Comment: Well gzip compresses files better than zstd. https://blog.cloudflare.com/squeezing-the-firehose/

Comment: BTW can you checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544074/how-to-make-restart-able-producer ?