# Continue Kafka producer transaction after producer restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The aim of having `transactional.id` configured for the producer is, in my understanding, to fence off a zombie producer and to proactively abort its transactions to avoid the need to wait for a timeout.

What I'm interested in doing is to be able to continue the transaction. For example:

```java
producer.beginTransaction();
producer.send(...);
// now the producer crashes

// start a new producer with same transactional.id
producer = new KafkaProducer(...); 
// this aborts the unfinished transaction of the previous producer
producer.initTransactions();
```

My gut feeling is that it should be possible, there's just no API for that. Is there anything that prevents us from doing that?

Why do I need this? The Kafka transaction in my case is a part of a larger distributed transaction, which failed during the 2nd phase. The transaction coordinator saved its state and was restarted and knows that some participants might have committed and some not, therefore it requires all participants to finish the commit from previous run.

Comment: A producer process can crash for many reason. Assume that somebody pull the cable of the host on which producer is running then what are you going to do? You need to consider make your producer restartable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544074/how-to-make-restart-able-producer

Comment: Assume my producer is restartable and after the restart it knows whether it wanted to commit or abort. It durably stores that before attempting to commit/abort.